# two different login with node-passport

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I have the same application for 2 sites, the front-site and the backoffice.Both sites require a different condition to login because the backoffice needs to have the is_admin value in "true".

this is my login method

```
module.exports.verifyCredentials = function (username, password, done) {

    mongoose.model("User").findOne({password:password, username:username, is_admin:true}, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });

};
```

and this is in my app.js

```
passport.use(new passportLocal.Strategy(securityCtl.verifyCredentials));

app.post("/administracion/login", passport.authenticate('local'), securityCtl.doLogin);
```

The doLogin methods just makes a redirect.

how can I send the frontsite login and the backoffice login to different methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use different names in each strategy and refers to they by their names in the `passport.authenticate` method. Now you can specify different methods (`verifyFrontSiteCredentials` for front-site and `verifyBackOfficeCredentials` for backoffice respectively) in each strategy. Something like this:

app.js

```
// front-site strategy
passport.use('front-site', new passportLocal.Strategy(securityCtl.verifyFrontSiteCredentials));

app.post("/administracion/front-site/login", passport.authenticate('front-site'), securityCtl.doLogin);

// backoffice strategy
passport.use('backoffice', new passportLocal.Strategy(securityCtl.verifyBackOfficeCredentials));

app.post("/administracion/backoffice/login", passport.authenticate('backoffice'), securityCtl.doLogin);
```

Comment: I'll give your bounty as soon as SO allow me to do it.  thanks